# Não consigo chamar os icones do bootstrap no laravel

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

Ola, não estou conseguindo chamar os icones do bootstrap no meu laravel, exemplo:

```
: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
```

Alguem sabe explicar o pq?

Comment: Aparece algo na página em vez do icon?

Comment: Não, fica em branco, caso eu use em um botão fica só o botão

Comment: A font está a ser incluída correctamente?

Comment: Você incluiu a pasta **fonts** e seus respectivos arquivos na pasta **public** do projeto. Tenta ver pelo console